# Side effect c++ vector copy and deletion

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, side-effects

I have this problem:

```
void foo(vector<int> &a){
    vector<int> b;
    b.push_back(1); // in general many push backs
    a = b;
}
```

since b is a local variable it will be deleted when foo ends. 
Will a retain the values inserted in b? 
I tried and it does but maybe is only due to chance.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT:

I think this answers my question. Isn't it?
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/
So basically a will retain the values in c++98. But I cannot fully understand what it does in c++11.

Comment: Why not `push_back` onto `a`?

Comment: What Jarod42 said. Also you can think about `a = std::move(b)`. That will make the assignment faster since no copys are necessary, at the cost that `b` afterwards contains garbage, which is fine, since it will die anyways.

Comment: You might want to consider returning that vector instead, if the only modification to `a` is this assignment. -- `a = foo();` is a side-effect that's easier to be spotted than `foo(a);`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a = b` will invoke the *copy assignment operator* of `std::vector`. This operator copies all the contents of the vector from `b` to `a` so `b` can be safely deleted afterwards.

Considering your edit:
This answer is also true for C++11. C++11 only adds a move assignment operator, but this operator is not invoked since `b` is not an r-value.

Even if `b` was an r-value (e.g., by wrapping b into a `std::move(b)`), then the move assignment operator would be invoked, which would also be fine. It would move the contents of `b` to `a`, so `b` would be an empty vector afterwards which can be safely deleted, as well.

Comment: Could the compiler be smart enough to figure that b will be destroyed just after and thus implicitely convert it to an rvalue?

Comment: @galinette Only if you return it (that's exactly what happens if you return a local non-reference variable whose type is the same type as the return type).

Comment: @galinette: In this case, it could be smart enough, but I don't think so. This optimization is not always applicable anyway (for example, if the constructors or destructors of the element type have side effects).

Comment: @dyp: This is not exactly true. What you mean is copy elision. But copy elision is not a move. It just constructs the return value right at where the caller wants to have it, so neither copy nor move here.

Comment: No, I don't mean copy elision. I mean [class.copy]/32, not /31: A named local variable in a return statement is treated as an rvalue in some cases. This is possible and safe since the local variable can't be referred to after the return statement. *Additionally*, this copy or move can be elided.

Comment: @dyp: Oh, right. Yeah, sure, a return value is an r-value :).

Comment: Umm I don't mean the return *value*. That's what the function returns. I really mean the local variable, whose name is an lvalue-expression. But copying *into* the return value is silly for objects whose lifetime will end soon anyway. So there's an additional language rule specifically for local variables that treats their names as rvalue expressions in return-statements under some circumstances (essentially the same requirements as for copy elision plus some relaxations).

Comment: @dyp: Right, of course, changed it. Concerning your comment above. I guess we ment the same thing here. I was just unable to articulate it correctly :).

Comment: I guess Standardese could be considered a distinct language ;)

Answer (score 2):

What happens in C++ 11 is that the assignment operator will do a copy unless you explicitly tell it to move using std::move.

To force the move you could do this:

```
void foo(vector<int> &a){
    vector<int> b;
    b.push_back(1); // in general many push backs
    a = std::move(b);
}
```

For this to work, vector has implemented the assignment operator for move something like this:

```
vector<T>& vector<T>::operator =(vector<T>&& to_move) {}
```

When using `std::move`, this tells the compiler to use the overloaded function that has implemented a move, otherwise it will fall back to `const vector<T>&` on older versions that have not implemented move semantics.

Move might or might not be faster depending on how this is implemented, but for vector you would expect the internal pointer to be moved from the old vector to the new vector, avoiding a copy of all contained objects.

e.g.

```
vector<T>& vector<T>::operator =(vector<T>&& to_move)
{
    delete [] m_ptrs;
    m_ptrs = to_move.m_ptrs;
    m_size = to_move.m_size;
    to_move.m_ptrs = nullptr;
    to_move.m_size = 0;
    return *this;
}
```

This is of course an educated guess, but hopefully it demonstrates what might happen when using move semantics.

Answer (score 1):

If those values are not pointers, they will be [copied](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator=/) in `a = b` so they will be preserved (They will be also previously copied in `b` when they are inserted http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/).

If they are, they will be also copied too but if they were pointing to local variables you will get a good collection of invalid pointers.

If, on the other hand, they were pointers to dynamically allocated memory you would not find any problem.